# How to specify a unicode and other escaped literals to Python 2.x ConfigParser

Tags: python, unicode, escaping, literals, configparser

I am using ConfigParser to read a config file.

I want the config files to stay in ASCII/ANSI, but I want to pass along a unicode literal (in the python literal sense) in one of the config options like this:

```
[flatfile]
datafile_encoding = utf16
delimiter= u'\u2016'
# also this should be parsable too:
# delimiter= '\t'
```

with the result being when I do:

```
import ConfigParser, io

config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser(allow_no_value=True)
config.read(filename)

flatfile_config = {}
for item in config.items('flatfile'):
    flatfile_config[item[0]] = item[1]

assert flatfile_config['delimiter'] == u'\u2016'
#assert flatfile_config['delimeter'] == '\t'

f = io.open(datafile, mode='r', encoding=flatfile_config['datafile_encoding'])
row = f.readline()
row_split = row.strip('\n').split(flatfile_config['delimiter'])
```

I'd like to not have to create an in-python lookup table to handle the literal values in the config file delimiter option (as I'm using the config file for that reason).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking to evaluate any Python literal exactly the same way Python would, the function [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) does what you want:

```
>>> s = r"""u'\u2016'"""
>>> print s
u'\u2016'
>>> print ast.literal_eval(s)
‖
```

---

If you want to make sure it's a string or Unicode literal *only*, so the user can't confuse you with `delimiter=42`, your best bet is to `literal_eval` and then type-check:

```
val = ast.literal_eval(s)
if not isinstance(val, basestring):
    raise BadUserError("Why are you giving me {} when I wanted a string?".format(s))
```

---

In more detail:

> Safely evaluate an expression node or a Unicode or Latin-1 encoded string containing a Python expression. The string or node provided may only consist of the following Python literal structures: strings, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans, and None.
>
> This can be used for safely evaluating strings containing Python expressions from untrusted sources without the need to parse the values oneself.

In case you're wondering what the worry is about untrusted sources, imagine that you just used `eval`, which works on any Python expression, and I put this in the config file:

```
delimiter=__import__('os').system('rm -rf /')
```